# How to calculate the limits of the integral and the outward vector? How to make change of variables in this proof?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, lebesgue-measure, harmonic-functions, surface-integrals, change-of-variable

I would like to see the calculations behind this proof I found here:
[Proof of polar coordinates theorem in Evans' PDE Book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2658241/proof-of-polar-coordinates-theorem-in-evans-pde-book)
That is, I am struggling to understand the following:

1. How do we calculate the limits of the integral and the outward normal vector in the proof below?
2. How can I make a change of variables from $\partial B(x_0,r)$ or $B(x_0, r)$ in order to obtain $\partial B(0,1)$ or $B(a+x_0t, r/2)$, with $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$? I mean, how can I calculate the limits of the integral, the outward normal vector, and the jacobian in this case?

I appreciate if you can help.

[image]

Comment: Which equality do you have trouble justifying? If you understand how the surface measure $dS$ is defined rigorously, you can prove all the equalities rigorously with a bit of computation. Evans assumes you already know it and have proved the famous polar coordinate formula, which he calls C.3

Comment: hi @Kakashi =D well, to be honest, I am struggling with all of them. But you are right, I wish to understand the proof of the polar coordinate formula (that I tried to prove but I failed),  AND I really would like to understand how to make change of variables in surfaces like in this case... So, do you know where can I find the proof of C.3 and a book that explains step by step how the surface measure dS (as you said) is defined rigorously with examples and exercises? I really wish to understand and not only this question but in any context to become independent in this... I hope.

Comment: @Kakashi For example I found this here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2658241/proof-of-polar-coordinates-theorem-in-evans-pde-book

However, all the calculations I would like to understand are not here. Is hidden. :(

Comment: I am going to change my question, then I thing is gonna be easier for someone to help, then I can really understand all (I hope).

Comment: You know the substitution formula for multidimensional functions?

Comment: Hi @stange :D. No, at least I don´t remember. So I do not know. What is?

Comment: Then you should definitely look it up, since otherwise you won't understand the proof of your formulas. This might also be the reason why you don't follow the answer in the link you provided above.

Comment: @stange I agree. Would you recommend me a book with all of this?

Comment: Have you read Theorem 5 on the same page of Evan's book and the comments afterwards? There you can find a reference.

Comment: Chapter 3.2 in page 119 of https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/analmv.pdf explains the surface measure in detail. Actually, the book uses the Riemann integral, but if you know measure theory, it's easy to formulate the results in terms of measures. For instance, (3.2.12) is defining the measure dS.

Comment: Thank you very much @Kakashi S2.

Comment: @stange I did not read until now. Thanks for your message. I was supposed to see this before, so I am sorry for the previous question.